# Extending dabbrev-expand

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, abbreviation

Has anybody tried extending the completion mechanism of `dabbrev-expand` to support different sorts of completion mechanism (defined in `minibuffer.el`)? I know of `mdabbrev-expand` but it only does *in-symbol* completion and its incomplete for example with respect to symbol characters in `emacs-lisp-mode`.

Comment: Do you know about [hippie expand](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HippieExpand)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) binds command `icicle-dabbrev-completion` to whatever keys standard `dabbrev-completion` is bound to -- typically <kbd>C-M-/</kbd>.

When there is only a single matching candidate, **Icicles** adds nothing to the party in this case.  But when there is more than one possibility `icicle-dabbrev-completion` lets you use several kinds of completion matching.

In particular, you can use [*apropos*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#PrefixAndAproposCompletion) completion, which means regexp matching (including substring matching).  You can also use [*progressive*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#ProgressiveCompletion) completion  and various kinds of [*fuzzy*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Fuzzy_Completion) completion (in addition to the vanilla completion styles in `minibuffer.el`).